# How do I combine multiple transformations and compute the relative pose?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, coordinate-systems, rotations

I have the following configuration:

- Sensor A which gives me at every point in time t a 3D translation vector and a rotation matrix: (R|T)_A_t relative to a static origin
- Sensor B. The position of sensor B relative to sensor A does not change in time and is statically defined by the rotation and translation matrix: (R|T)_A_to_B

  - Meaning both sensors move together (mounted on the same vehicle)

I compute the relative pose from Sensor A at time t to time 0 like that:
(R|T)_A_0_to_t = inverse( (R|T)_A_0 ) * (R|T)_A_t

But how do I get now the relative pose from Sensor B at time t to Sensor A at time 0? Meaning (R|T)_B_0_to_t?

Comment: Welcome to math.se. You will have to simplify your question quite a bit before anyone will be willing to answer it, otherwise math.se may not be the right place to post such a question.

Comment: Is it now easier to understand?